# Django readonly form field does not appear in cleaned data

Tags: django

in my forms I changed this field to readonly

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
...
     database = forms.CharField(label='Database', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs='style':'width:164px','readonly':'readonly'}), initial='production')
```

I can see the initial value in the form on the browser, but then when I try to retrieve the values in the code

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ReportForm, self).clean()
        print "CLEANED DATA ",cleaned_data
        database = cleaned_data['database'] # this throws an error
```

The cleaned_data has all the other form items except the database
it worked fine before adding attrs readonly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The data for read-only fields are not available in cleaned_data.** This is because read-only fields are displayed as text rather than as input elements, and thus are not posted back to the server, and so are not in the data that gets cleaned.